# Migrating Chrome extension user data kept in local storage to the new version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have Chrome extension which store user data in local storage. Now I'm developing an update I have to migrate user data to new version when they update to new version.

When I try this

```
chrome.storage.local.get([old save name], result => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
})
```

it's empty.

What is the issue? I try the new version on developer mode I guess the new version is acting like totally different extension, maybe when I publish it will works well.

Comment: Maybe you confuse `localStorage` with `chrome.storage.local`? Otherwise, show where/how this code runs.

Comment: Yes I guess I do. Then how can I migrate the data from chrome.storage.local?

Comment: There's no need to migrate anything if it already was chrome.storage.local. Check your previous code and see which storage you were using, don't guess.

Comment: Yes now I'm very sure I use chrome.storage.local. But when I try to get in new version packet it's empty, it can't see the data of the old version.

Comment: It means a bug in Chrome or you deleted the data or you look in the wrong console or your extension has a different id (e.g. you test it locally).